# iframe not showing on website after publishing

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

My iframe works well in the development environment. But after publishing the iframe is not working. I have attached the code.

```
<iframe id="ytVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XACzyRmQm54"></iframe>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("card1").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/XACzyRmQm54";
};
document.getElementById("card2").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/v5pg_Nw1lak";
};
document.getElementById("card3").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
    "https://www.youtube.com/embed/4fZU39FM-zg";
    
};
document.getElementById("card4").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/fZftnqXlU4g";
    
};
</script>
```

Comment: Does it show any errors in console?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. “Not working” is not a sufficient problem description - so give a _proper_ one. Also provide a [mre], if that helps with understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me. let's check your html code. I made like this:

```
<body>
    <button id="card1">Button1</button>
    <button id="card2">Button2</button>
    <button id="card3">Button3</button>
    <button id="card4">Button4</button>
    <iframe id="ytVideo" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XACzyRmQm54"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("card1").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XACzyRmQm54";
};
document.getElementById("card2").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/v5pg_Nw1lak";
};
document.getElementById("card3").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = 
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/4fZU39FM-zg";

};
document.getElementById("card4").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById('ytVideo').src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/fZftnqXlU4g";

};
    </script>
</body>
```